# how to create a new vector via loop

Tags: r

a)  Create a vector X of length 20, with the kth element in X = 2k, for k=1…20. Print out the values of X.

b)  Create a vector Y of length 20, with all elements in Y equal to 0. Print out the values of Y.

c)  Using a for loop, reassigns the value of the k-th element in Y, for k = 1…20. When k < 12, the kth element of Y is reassigned as the cosine of k. When the k ≥ 12, the kth element of Y is reassigned as the value of integral sqrt(t)dt from 0 to K.

for the first two questions, it is simple.

```
 > x1 <- seq(1,20,by=2) 
 > x <- 2 * x1 
 > x
  [1]  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40
 > y <- rep(0,20)
 > y
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

i got stuck on the last one,

```
 t <- function(i) sqrt(i)
 for (i in 1:20) {
   if (i < 12) {
  y[i] <- cos(i)
  }
   else if (i >= 12) {
   y[i] <- integral(t, lower= 0, Upper = 20)
  }
  }
  y // print new y
```

Any suggestions?  thanks.

Comment: The structure of your question, implies this is homework...  Please clearly note this. And thank you for posting the code you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest you almost have it ready and it is good that you have showed some code here:

```
y <- rep(0,20) #y vector from question 2

for ( k in 1:20) {              #start the loop
  if (k < 12) {                 #if k less than 12
    y[k] <- cos(k)              #calculate cosine
  } else if( k >= 12) {         #else if k greater or equal to 12
    y[k] <- integrate( sqrt, lower=0, upper=k)$value #see below for explanation
}
}
print(y) #prints y

> print(y)
 [1]  0.540302306 -0.416146837 -0.989992497 -0.653643621  0.283662185  0.960170287  0.753902254 -0.145500034 -0.911130262 -0.839071529  0.004425698
[12] 27.712816032 31.248114562 34.922139530 38.729837810 42.666671456 46.728535669 50.911693960 55.212726149 59.628486093
```

First of all `stats::integrate` is the function you need to calculate the integral

```
 integrate( sqrt, lower=0, upper=2)$value
```

The first argument is a function which in your case is `sqrt`. `sqrt` is defined already in R so there is no need to define it yourself explicitly as `t <- function(i) sqrt(i)`

The other two arguments as you correctly set in your code are `lower` and `upper`.

The function `integrate( sqrt, lower=0, upper=2)` will return:

```
1.885618 with absolute error < 0.00022
```

and that is why you need `integrate( sqrt, lower=0, upper=2)$value` to only extract the value.

Type `?integrate` in your console to see the documentation which will help you a lot I think.

Comment: You are welcome abs27. Glad it helped! Make sure to read my comment under your question it will help you in the future I think :)

Comment: Certainly, $value helps indeed.

Comment: I meant the comment below the question in your original post about accepting answers, but `$value` is kind of helpful too :)

Answer (score 2):

What may help is that the command to calculate a one-dimensional integral is `integrate` not `integral`.

You have successfully completed the first two, so I'll demonstrate a different way of getting those vectors:

```
x <- 2 * seq_len(20)
y <- double(length = 20)
```

As for your function, you have the right idea, but you need to clean up your syntax a bit. For example, you may need to double-check your braces (using a set style like [Hadley Wickham's](http://stat405.had.co.nz/r-style.html) will help you prevent syntax errors and make the code more readable), you don't need the "if" in the else, you need to read up on `integrate` and see what its inputs, and importantly its *outputs* are (and which of them you need and how to extract it), and lastly, you need to `return` a value from your function. Hopefully, that's enough to help you work it out on your own. Good Luck!

### Update

#### Slightly different function to demonstrate coding style and some best practices with loops

Given a working answer has been posted, this is what I did when looking at your question. I think it is worth posting, as as I think that it is a good habit to 1) pre-allocate answers 2) prevent confusion about scope by not re-using the input variable name as an output and 3) use the seq_len and seq_along constructions for for loops, per R Inferno(pdf) which is required reading, in my opinion:

```
tf <- function(y){
  z <- double(length = length(y))
  for (k in seq_along(y)) {
    if (k < 12) {
      z[k] <- cos(k)
    } else {
      z[k] <- integrate(f = sqrt, lower = 0, upper = k)$value
    }
  }
  return(z)
}
```

Which returns:

```
> tf(y)
 [1]  0.540302306 -0.416146837 -0.989992497 -0.653643621  0.283662185  0.960170287  0.753902254 
 [8] -0.145500034 -0.911130262 -0.839071529  0.004425698 27.712816032 31.248114562 34.922139530
[15] 38.729837810 42.666671456 46.728535669 50.911693960 55.212726149 59.628486093
```

Comment: I agree with everything you say but he doesn't use a function with his `for-loop`

Comment: @LyzandeR, true. I would have built the function slightly differently than you have. I might as well post it, now that straight answers are being given 8-)

Comment: I haven't downvoted by the way as you can see from my profile (0 downvotes). In fact I upvoted. Some people get annoyed I think when someone posts a similar answer as someone else. I do not mind it but please specify next to your update that you provide an improvement of my code or else we will end up receiving down votes I think...

Comment: @LyzandeR, as often happens in SO, you can tell from the timestamp that we were posting at the same time (I hit save 4 minutes before you did, but left out the function). I don't mind deleting the update, if it concerns you.

Comment: Not at all. Please do leave it in. I always say that every contribution is welcome. I am only concerned of people accidentally down voting us as it might have happened now with you. Please, keep it in as it adds value. I am not concerned at all.

Comment: @LyzandeR, I hope you find the above better. I'm relatively new to SO (as opposed to CrossValidated and MathExchange), so please forgive me as I wade into the deeper end of the pool.

Comment: Cool! Everything's great! No need to apologize for anything :)